# Nodemcu single server with 2 clients

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, sensors, nodemcu, data

I am trying to connect my nodemcu server with 2 nodemcu clients. One client is connected and it works perfectly. I am unable to configure what to do for the other client to be connected and share data through server.
Server Code

```
/*
Geekstips.com
IoT project - Communication between two ESP8266 - Talk with Each Other
ESP8266 Arduino code example
*/
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
// IoT platform Credentials
String apiKey = "PBD5LAJC4BSV3OKC";
const char* logServer = "api.thingspeak.com";

// Internet router credentials
const char* ssid = "Dhamaal";
const char* password = "03334204224";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);
WiFiClient client;
char * ssid_ap = "ESP_AP";
char * password_ap = "123456789";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  setupAccessPoint();
}
// Handling the / root web page from my server
void handle_index() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Get the f**k out from my server!");
}

// Handling the /feed page from my server
void handle_feed() {
  String t = server.arg("temp");
  String h = server.arg("hum");
  String s = server.arg("moi");

  server.send(200, "text/plain", "This is response to client");
  setupStMode(t, h, s);
}

void setupAccessPoint(){
  Serial.println("** SETUP ACCESS POINT **");
  Serial.println("- disconnect from any other modes");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  Serial.println("- start ap with SID: "+ String(ssid));
  WiFi.softAP(ssid_ap, password_ap);
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("- AP IP address is :");
  Serial.print(myIP);
  setupServer();
}

void setupServer(){
  Serial.println("** SETUP SERVER **");
  Serial.println("- starting server :");
  server.on("/", handle_index);
  server.on("/feed", handle_feed);
  server.begin();
};

void setupStMode(String t, String v, String m){
  Serial.println("** SETUP STATION MODE **");
  Serial.println("- disconnect from any other modes");
  WiFi.disconnect();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("- connecting to Home Router SID: **********");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("- succesfully connected");
  Serial.println("- starting client");

  WiFiClient client;

  Serial.println("- connecting to Database server: " + String(logServer));
  if (client.connect(logServer, 80)) {
    Serial.println("- succesfully connected");
    String postStr = apiKey;
    postStr += "&field1=";
    postStr += String(t);
    postStr += "&field2=";
    postStr += String(v);
    postStr += "&field3=";
    postStr += String(m);
    postStr += "\r\n\r\n";
    Serial.println("- sending data...");
    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + apiKey + "\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(postStr.length());
    client.print("\n\n");
    client.print(postStr);
  }
  client.stop();
  //Serial.println("- stopping the client");
  /// If your ESP does not respond you can just
  // reset after each request sending 
  //Serial.println("- trying reset");
  //ESP.reset();

}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

and my client code is

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#define DHTPIN 0

// AP Wi-Fi credentials
const char* ssid = "ESP_AP";
const char* password = "123456789";

// Local ESP web-server address
String serverHost = "http://192.168.4.1/feed";
String data;
// DEEP_SLEEP Timeout interval
int sleepInterval = 1;
// DEEP_SLEEP Timeout interval when connecting to AP fails
int failConnectRetryInterval = 2;
int counter = 0;
float s;
float h;
float t;
// Static network configuration
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 4, 4);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHT11);
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  ESP.eraseConfig();
  WiFi.persistent(false);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(2000);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("**************************");
  Serial.println("**************************");
  Serial.println("******** BEGIN ***********");
  Serial.println("- start sensors");
  dht.begin();
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("- set ESP STA mode");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.println("- connecting to wifi");
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet); 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    if(counter > 20){
       Serial.println("- can't connect, going to sleep");    
       //hibernate(failConnectRetryInterval);
    }
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    counter++;
  }

  Serial.println("- wifi connected");
  Serial.println("- read DHT sensor");
  readDHTSensor();
  Serial.println("- build DATA stream string");
  buildDataStream();
  Serial.println("- send GET request");
  sendHttpRequest();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("- got back to sleep");
  Serial.println("**************************");
  Serial.println("**************************");
  hibernate(sleepInterval); 
}

void sendHttpRequest() {
  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(serverHost);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.POST(data);
  http.writeToStream(&Serial);
  http.end();
}

void readDHTSensor() {
  delay(200);
   s = analogRead(A0);
  h = dht.readHumidity();
  t = dht.readTemperature();
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
    t = 0.00;
    h = 0.00;
  }
  Serial.println("- temperature read : "+String(t));
  Serial.println("- humidity read : "+String(h));
  Serial.println("- moisture read : "+String(s));
}

void buildDataStream() {
  data = "temp=";
  data += String(t);
  data += "&hum=";
  data += String(h);
  data += "&moi=";
  data += String(s);
  Serial.println("- data stream: "+data);
}


 void hibernate(int pInterval) {
  WiFi.disconnect();
  ESP.deepSleep(120e6);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {


}
```

Kindly help me to change my code so it can be connected with server.

Comment: and where is the problem? set a different IP for the other client and that is all

Comment: I am confused for that how server will understand that data coming from which ip? i want to send data of both clients on different thingspeak channel.

Comment: send some id as parameter

Comment: and what changes must be reflected on server?

Comment: read the additional parameter